# Date not in mail

Tags: php

I have the following script to send email using SMTP authentication. Everything works fine but date is not shown in my inbox for this mail. It is marked as '?'. Can anybody help me?

```
 require_once "Mail.php";

 $from = "test@example";
 $to = $mailto;
 $subject = $subject;
 $body = $msg;

 $host = "test.com";
 $username = "uname";
 $password = "password";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject,
    'Content-type'=>'text/html');
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   //echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
     return false;
  } else {
   //echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
     return true;
  }
```

The from,host,username and password values shown here are only test values for security.

Is it any problem with mail headers?

Comment: For future reference: the use of `example.com` is advised in examples/tests. `test.com` is an existing domain. What date are you talking about? The sending/receiving one? And if so, what does the body of the mail say, and what email-client are you using?

Answer (score 5):

solved it? this worked for me, i just added in the headers array:

```
'Date'      => date('r', time()),
```